# 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, string

I would like to read some characters from a string `s1` and put it into another string `s2`.

However, assigning to `s2[j]` gives an error:

```py
s2[j] = s1[i]

# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

---

In C, this works:

```cpp
int i = j = 0;
while (s1[i] != '\0')
    s2[j++] = s1[i++];
```

My attempt in Python:

```py
s1 = "Hello World"
s2 = ""
j = 0

for i in range(len(s1)):
    s2[j] = s1[i]
    j = j + 1
```

Comment: Btw, don't name your variables after python builtins. If you use `str` as a variable here, you will be unable to do string conversions with `str(var_that_is_not_a_string)` or type comparisions such as `type(var_with_unknown_type) == str`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752946/replacing-a-character-from-a-certain-index/41753038 to fix `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`.

Comment: Also relevant: [Why do we need tuples in Python (or any immutable data type)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174124)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

In Python, strings are immutable, so you can't change their characters in-place.

You can, however, do the following:

```
for c in s1:
    s2 += c
```

The reasons this works is that it's a shortcut for:

```
for c in s1:
    s2 = s2 + c
```

The above *creates a new string* with each iteration, and stores the reference to that new string in `s2`.

Comment: Then if I would to read the characters from the string and copy them some where, then how can I do that?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: It depends on what you need to do with those characters. In my answer I've shown how they can be appended to another string.

Comment: I would like to write a program "Hello world" to "World Hello". So my code should search for space (' '). So I was looking for help

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: `print " ".join(reversed("Hello world".split())).capitalize()`

Comment: I wanted to know how that affects memory, for example, if I'm dealing with code which has to do this for millions of times, would the new created strings in each iteration get garbage collected or what.. i'm just hopelessly confused here

Comment: @ronnieaka In older versions of Python, this would indeed generate huge amounts of of garbage. Modern ones can sometimes optimize (which is one of the advantages of a language that _doesn't_ make guarantees about underlying implementation details), but it's better not to rely on that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316887/what-is-the-most-efficient-string-concatenation-method-in-python

Comment: would 2.7 be called as old version?

Answer (score 199):

The other answers are correct, but you can, of course, do something like:

```
>>> str1 = "mystring"
>>> list1 = list(str1)
>>> list1[5] = 'u'
>>> str1 = ''.join(list1)
>>> print(str1)
mystrung
>>> type(str1)
<type 'str'>
```

if you really want to.

Answer (score 27):

> assigning to `s2[j]` gives an error

[Strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) are immutable so what you've done in C won't be possible in Python. Instead, you'll have to create a new string.

> I would like to read some characters from a string and put it into
> other string.

Use a [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice):

```
>>> s1 = 'Hello world!!'
>>> s2 = s1[6:12]
>>> print(s2)
world!
```

Answer (score 5):

Strings in Python are immutable (you cannot change them inplace).

What you are trying to do can be done in many ways:

Copy the string:

```
foo = 'Hello'
bar = foo
```

Create a new string by joining all characters of the old string:

```
new_string = ''.join(c for c in oldstring)
```

Slice and copy:

```
new_string = oldstring[:]
```

Comment: `bar = foo` does not copy a string.

Answer (score 5):

### Performant methods

If you are frequently performing index replacements, a more performant and memory-compact method is to convert to a different data structure. Then, convert back to string when you're done.

#### list:

Easiest and simplest:

```
s = "TEXT"
s = list(s)
s[1] = "_"
s = "".join(s)
```

#### bytearray (ASCII):

This method uses less memory. The memory is also contiguous, though that doesn't really matter much in Python if you're doing single-element random access anyways:

```
ENC_TYPE = "ascii"
s = "TEXT"
s = bytearray(s, ENC_TYPE)
s[1] = ord("_")
s = s.decode(ENC_TYPE)
```

#### bytearray (UTF-32):

More generally, for characters outside the base ASCII set, I recommend using UTF-32 (or sometimes UTF-16), which will ensure alignment for random access:

```
ENC_TYPE = "utf32"
ENC_WIDTH = 4

def replace(s, i, replacement):
    start = ENC_WIDTH * (i + 1)
    end = ENC_WIDTH * (i + 1 + len(replacement))
    s[start:end] = bytearray(replacement, ENC_TYPE)[ENC_WIDTH:]


s = "TEXT HI ひ RA ら GA が NA な DONE"
s = bytearray(s, ENC_TYPE)
replace(s, 1, "_")
s = s.decode(ENC_TYPE)
```

Though this method may be more memory-compact than using `list`, it does require many more operations.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers convert the string to a list or construct a new string character by character.  These methods can be costly, especially for large strings.  Instead, we can use slicing to get the parts of the string before and after the character that is changed, and combine those with the new character.

Here I modify the example code from [Crowman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18006499/12808884) to replace a single character in the string using string slicing instead of conversion to a list.

```
>>> str1 = "mystring"
>>> pos = 5
>>> new_char = 'u'
>>> str2 = str1[:pos] + new_char + str1[pos+1:]
>>> print(str2)
mystrung
>>> type(str2)
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another approach if you wanted to swap out a specific character for another character:

```
def swap(input_string):
   if len(input_string) == 0:
     return input_string
   if input_string[0] == "x":
     return "y" + swap(input_string[1:])
   else:
     return input_string[0] + swap(input_string[1:])
```

Answer (score -2):

How about this solution:

str="Hello World" (as stated in problem)
srr = str+ ""

Answer (score -2):

Hi you should try the string split method:

```
i = "Hello world"
output = i.split()

j = 'is not enough'

print 'The', output[1], j
```

Answer (score -2):

The 'str' is an immutable data type. Therefore str type object doesn't support item assignment.

```
s1 = "Hello World"
s2 = ['']*len(s1)
j = 0
for i in range(len(s1)):
s2[j]=s1[i]
j = j + 1
print(''.join(s2)) # Hello World
```