# function to remove vowels from string

Tags: python

I tried to define a function that removes vowels from a string. An error was detected at line 4 that reads: 
"TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment".
Could somebody please explain in simple terms what this error is about and how to fix it?

```
def del_vowel(text):
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i].lower() in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
            text[i] = ""
    return text
text = raw_input('> ')
print del_vowel(text)
```

Comment: string are immutable in python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Duplicate explaining the error: ['str' object does not support item assignment in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10631473/7851470)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable objects you can not change them in-place.Instead you can use `str.replace` to remove the characters :

```
text.replace(character, "")
```

Also in your code you don't need to use `range`, since strings are iterable you can loop over the string and check the existence of each character in list of vowels.

```
def del_vowel(text):
    for i in text:
        if i.lower() in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
            text.replace(i,"")
    return text
```

But a more pythonic way you can use `str.translate` to remove some character from your string.

Read the following question for more info :[Remove specific characters from a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner using [Generator Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
"".join([char if char not in ['a','e','i','o','u'] else "" for char in text])
```