# Python: Hangman TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, string, list

I'm currently making a hangman program but I am stuck. Whenever I enter a correct guess for the word I keep getting the error 'str' object does not support item assignment.

Here is my code:

```
import random

def displayBoard(randomWord):
    board = []
    for i in randomWord:
        board.append(' _ ')
    return ''.join(board)

def gameGuesses(randomWord):
    newBoard = displayBoard(randomWord)
    print(newBoard)
    mistakes = 6
    count = 0
    while not False and mistakes > 0:
       letterInput = input("\nPlease input a letter: ").upper()
       if letterInput in randomWord:
          letter = randomWord.index(letterInput)
          while count != letter:
              count += 1
              if count == letter:
                  >>>newBoard[count] = letterInput<<<#PROBLEM


       else:
           mistakes = mistakes - 1
           print("Incorrect letter.",mistakes,"remaining.")




wordList = ["Python","Hello","Random"]
randomWord = random.choice(wordList).upper()
gameGuesses(randomWord)
```

The problem is at newBoard[count] = letterInput. How am I supposed to replace the underscore with the correct letter inputted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['str' object does not support item assignment in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631473/str-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-in-python)

Comment: I have looked at that already and it does not help my case whatsoever

Comment: You try to mutate string - duplicate states that it's impossible and shows an alternatives. Stripping your code to relevant issue is straightforward duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newBoard` is a string and strings are *immutable* in Python - that's why item assignment is not allowed.

You must build a new string. For example, if you wanted to replace the character at position 4 (the o) in `'helloworld'`, you'd issue

```
>>> s = 'helloworld'
>>> s = s[:4] + 'X' + s[5:]
>>> s
'hellXworld'
```

Another option would be to use a bytearray:

```
>>> s = bytearray('helloworld')    
>>> print(s)
helloworld
>>> s[4] = 'X'
>>> print(s)
hellXworld
```

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot!