# Python beginner here : TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

I just started programming with python a couple days ago with no prior experience in programming.

I've been following tutorials online and decided to challenge myself by making a hangman-esque game. I'm trying to make it so that a guess replaces the position an alphabet in the hidden word but python is returning this error. Right now the word is called name and the hidden_name are just #'s in the same length.

```
    name = input ("what is your name ::")
    hidden_name = ("#" * len(name))
    print (hidden_name)

    guess = input ("Guess a letter ::")
    def guess_update(guess, name, hidden_name):
        right = guess in name 
        i = 0
        for c in name:
            if c == guess:
                hidden_name[i] = c
            i += 1
    if guess in name:
        guess_update(guess, name, hidden_name)
        print ("Your progess is ::", hidden_name)
```

Thanks for helping this newbie out :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['str' object does not support item assignment in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631473/str-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-in-python)

Answer (score 6):

Strings in Python are immutable, so you cannot do this:

```
hidden_name[i] = c
```

One option which will achieve the desired effect for your game is:

```
hidden_name = hidden_name[:i] + c + hidden_name[i+1:]
```

This works because you are creating a new string using concatenation, and re-assigning the result back to the variable, rather than attempting to edit the existing string.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in python are inmutable, so you cannot change its content.
One solution would be to split the string, change the letter and stick it back together:

```
splitted = list(hidden_name)
splitted[i] = c
hidden_name = ''.join(splitted)
```

Comment: Thanks guys, i think i get it now. So strings are immutable but lists are. So I could either change the word to a list( then replace that character), or split and insert the character into a string?