# String object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, string, variable-assignment

As a starting programmer I am currently working on a hangman project, in which the given letters must return every time. Therefore I would like to work with a list that returns with the by the player given letters. However, this gives me the following issue:

```
  File "Hangman.py", line 65, in <module>
    word_blank[i] = guess
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

This is for the following part of my code:

```
while game_on == 'yes':
    answer = select_word(selection)
    if answer != 'error123':
        word_blank = answer_form(answer)
        break

# start guessing letters
count = 1
guesses = []

while count <= 10:
    print(f'\n\nYour guess count:\t{count}')
    print(f'Your guesses:\t\t{guesses}')
    guess = input('Guess a letter: ').lower()
    count += 1
    guesses.append(guess)

    for i in range(0, len(answer)):
        if answer[i] == guess:
            word_blank[i] = guess
            break

    print(' '.join(word_blank))

print('\n\nGame over..')
```

With answer form being:

```
def answer_form(answer):
    word_blank = []
    word_blank.extend(answer)

    for i in range(0, len(word_blank)):
        word_blank[i] = '_'

    return(' '.join(word_blank))
```

I have checked various answers on Stack Overflow already, but unfortunately I cannot relate these well to my personal code. I felt the solution in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631473/str-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-in-python) came close, but unfortunately it has been without results. How should I improve my code to get rid of the error, while being able to stay within the loop to add all the guessed letters to `word_blank[i]`?

Comment: Where do you initialize word_blank? You need to show all the relevant code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change one character in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/change-one-character-in-a-string)

Comment: @CupinaCoffee I added the parts where word_blank initializes and how it is constructed.

Comment: strings are immutable - meaing: you can not change them. You can create a new one, f.e. by slicing: `s = "abcdk"` and then `s = s[:-1]+""efghij" + s[-1]`. For your game, use a list of characters, you can manipulate them easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your `def answer_form(answer):` returns a joined list - making it a string. You can not modify strings, they are immutable (see f.e. [Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types)). You can however recreate them, f.e. by slicing or using them as list of characters. See [Change one character in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/change-one-character-in-a-string) for that.

---

You can simplify your hangman if you use [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). It is easier to print `'_'` for any character that was not guessed yet, then manipulating strings (and you avoid manipulating lists as well ;o):

```
data = ["hang","man","carrot","supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"]

# random.choice solver (I am lazy ;o) ) - set to False for human player
autosolve = True

import random
from string import ascii_lowercase 
aslow = set(ascii_lowercase) 

# what should the user guess? random choice from data
what = random.choice(data).lower()

# store the length and characters used in what instead of calculating each time
lwhat = len(what)
swhat = set(what)
# these letters where already guessed 
guessed = set()

# amount of tries reached, we quit when twice the amount of characters got tried
tries = 0
while True and tries < 2*lwhat:

    # use list comprehension to print _ if a char was not guessed yet, else print char
    print("The secret word is: ", ' '.join(x if x in guessed else "_" for x in what))

    # we are done if all characters of what are guessed 
    if swhat.issubset(guessed):
        print(f"You did it! It took you {tries} tries") 
        break

    if not autosolve: 
        guess = input("Guess one letter or the complete word:").lower() 
    else:
        guess = random.choice(list(aslow))
        print("Guess one letter or the complete word:", guess)
        aslow.remove(guess)

    lguess = len(guess)

    # only count 1-character and full word guesses
    if lguess not in (1,lwhat):
        print("1 letter or the while word, try again") 
        continue

    tries += 1
    # one character was guessed
    if lguess == 1:
        guessed.add(guess) # add to set and print some feedback
        if guess in what:  
            print("Correct.")
        else:
            print("beeeeeep - that was wrong.")

    # whole word was guessed
    elif guess == what:
        print(f"You did it! It took you {tries} tries") 
        break
else:
    print("Too many tries: try again later")

print("The end")
```

The win-condition is: the set of the word you look for [is a subset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) of all guessed characters.

Output:

```
The secret word is:  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
Guess one letter or the complete word: s
Correct.
The secret word is:  s _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s
Guess one letter or the complete word: n
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  s _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s
Guess one letter or the complete word: b
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  s _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s
Guess one letter or the complete word: v
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  s _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s
Guess one letter or the complete word: j
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  s _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s
Guess one letter or the complete word: e
Correct.
The secret word is:  s _ _ e _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s _ _ _ e _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s
Guess one letter or the complete word: q
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  s _ _ e _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s _ _ _ e _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s
Guess one letter or the complete word: g
Correct.
The secret word is:  s _ _ e _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ g _ _ _ s _ _ _ e _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s
Guess one letter or the complete word: x
Correct.
The secret word is:  s _ _ e _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ g _ _ _ s _ _ _ e x _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s
Guess one letter or the complete word: w
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  s _ _ e _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ g _ _ _ s _ _ _ e x _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ s
Guess one letter or the complete word: u
Correct.
The secret word is:  s u _ e _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ g _ _ _ s _ _ _ e x _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ u s
Guess one letter or the complete word: o
Correct.
The secret word is:  s u _ e _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ g _ _ _ s _ _ _ e x _ _ _ _ _ _ o _ _ o u s
Guess one letter or the complete word: t
Correct.
The secret word is:  s u _ e _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ g _ _ _ s t _ _ e x _ _ _ _ _ _ o _ _ o u s
Guess one letter or the complete word: c
Correct.
The secret word is:  s u _ e _ c _ _ _ _ _ _ g _ _ _ s t _ c e x _ _ _ _ _ _ o c _ o u s
Guess one letter or the complete word: m
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  s u _ e _ c _ _ _ _ _ _ g _ _ _ s t _ c e x _ _ _ _ _ _ o c _ o u s
Guess one letter or the complete word: h
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  s u _ e _ c _ _ _ _ _ _ g _ _ _ s t _ c e x _ _ _ _ _ _ o c _ o u s
Guess one letter or the complete word: f
Correct.
The secret word is:  s u _ e _ c _ _ _ f _ _ g _ _ _ s t _ c e x _ _ _ _ _ _ o c _ o u s
Guess one letter or the complete word: i
Correct.
The secret word is:  s u _ e _ c _ _ i f _ _ g i _ i s t i c e x _ i _ _ i _ o c i o u s
Guess one letter or the complete word: k
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  s u _ e _ c _ _ i f _ _ g i _ i s t i c e x _ i _ _ i _ o c i o u s
Guess one letter or the complete word: d
Correct.
The secret word is:  s u _ e _ c _ _ i f _ _ g i _ i s t i c e x _ i _ _ i d o c i o u s
Guess one letter or the complete word: y
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  s u _ e _ c _ _ i f _ _ g i _ i s t i c e x _ i _ _ i d o c i o u s
Guess one letter or the complete word: a
Correct.
The secret word is:  s u _ e _ c a _ i f _ a g i _ i s t i c e x _ i a _ i d o c i o u s
Guess one letter or the complete word: r
Correct.
The secret word is:  s u _ e r c a _ i f r a g i _ i s t i c e x _ i a _ i d o c i o u s
Guess one letter or the complete word: p
Correct.
The secret word is:  s u p e r c a _ i f r a g i _ i s t i c e x p i a _ i d o c i o u s
Guess one letter or the complete word: l
Correct.
The secret word is:  s u p e r c a l i f r a g i l i s t i c e x p i a l i d o c i o u s
You did it! It took you 25 tries
The end
```

The "AI" is really bad for short words though:

```
The secret word is:  _ _ _ _ _ _
Guess one letter or the complete word: q
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  _ _ _ _ _ _
Guess one letter or the complete word: v
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  _ _ _ _ _ _
Guess one letter or the complete word: p
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  _ _ _ _ _ _
Guess one letter or the complete word: o
Correct.
The secret word is:  _ _ _ _ o _
Guess one letter or the complete word: y
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  _ _ _ _ o _
Guess one letter or the complete word: a
Correct.
The secret word is:  _ a _ _ o _
Guess one letter or the complete word: d
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  _ a _ _ o _
Guess one letter or the complete word: w
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  _ a _ _ o _
Guess one letter or the complete word: m
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  _ a _ _ o _
Guess one letter or the complete word: i
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
The secret word is:  _ a _ _ o _
Guess one letter or the complete word: t
Correct.
The secret word is:  _ a _ _ o t
Guess one letter or the complete word: j
beeeeeep - that was wrong.
Too many tries: try again later
The end
```