# Having issues in replacing values of the array in python code

Tags: python

> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

I am taking a 11 digit number as input in `recieved_code`, later on after getting the error position, I want to replace that digit with 0 or 1 depending on the condition.

```
recieved_code = (input())

#Detecting the position of error

parList = parList[: : -1]
error = 0
for i in range(0,len(parList)):
    error = error + pow(2,i)*parList[i]
print("\nError is at position:",error)

#Correcting the error
if recieved_code[error-1] == 1:
    print("It's 1")
    recieved_code[error-1] = 0
else:
    print("It's 0")
    recieved_code[error-1] = 1

print("Corrected code:",recieved_code)
```

I wanted 0 to be replaced by 1, or 1 to be replaced by 0.

[image: This is the error]

Comment: Python Strings are immutable. Possible duplicate of ['str' object does not support item assignment in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631473/str-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Strings are immutable

That means that once created, you **can't modify** the string itself. You need to create another one after processing/concatenating/etc...

Comment: Can you please give me the solution