# Adding a column to a pandas DataFrame from unpacking a zipped list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to read a list of HTML files into pandas DataFrames.

1. Each HTML file has multiple dataframes ( I have used pd.concat to combine them ) .
2. The HTML file names contains a string which I would like to add as a column.

```
# Read all files into a list
files = glob.glob('monthly_*.html')

# Zip the dfs with the desired string segment
zipped_dfs = [zip(pd.concat(pd.read_html(file)), file.split('_')[1]) for file in files]
```

I am having trouble unpacking the zipped list of ( df, product ).

```
dfs = []

# Loop through the list of zips, 
for _zip in zipped_dfs:

    # Unpack the zip
    for _df, product in _zip:

        # Adding the product string as a new column
        _df['Product'] = product
        dfs.append(_df)
```

However, I am getting the error `'str' object does not support item assignment`

Could someone explain the best way to add the new column ?

Comment: Have you made sure that `zipped_dfs` has the right values?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['str' object does not support item assignment in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631473/str-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `zip` line from the list comprehension. If you want a tuple of the concatenated dataframes and the product name, then you should write:

```
zipped_dfs = [(pd.concat(pd.read_html(file)), file.split('_')[1]) 
              for file in files]
```

However, the intermediate step of creating a list of tuples is not needed. The entire approach can be simplified as follows:

```
dfs = []
for file in glob.glob('monthly_*.html'):
    # NOTE: your code seemingly keeps .html in the product name
    # so I modified the split operation
    df = pd.concat(pd.read_html(file))
    df['Product'] = file.split('.html')[0].split('_')[1]     
    dfs.append(df)
```