# Swapping first charachters of a string Python

Tags: python, string, swap

So I tried to swap the first characters of the strings. Fresh > Nresh and Not fresh > Fot fresh, what am I doing wrong here? I got this error message: string_A[0] = string_B[0:1]
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Here my code:

```
string_A = "Fresh"
string_B = "Not fresh"

placeholder = string_A[0]
string_A[0] = string_B[0]
string_B[0] = string_A[0]

print(string_A)
print(string_B)
```

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: This question has been at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631473/str-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-in-python/18006499

Comment: As alternative to the answers under the link provided above, `string_A.replace(string_A[0], string_B[0], 1)` would yield the behavior you're looking for; under the hood it's not different from what is presented, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the string objects as they are immutable.

You can overwrite them using slicing:

```
string_A = "Fresh"
string_B = "Not fresh"

placeholder = string_A[0]
string_A = string_B[0] + string_A[1:]
string_B = placeholder + string_B[1:]

print(string_A)
print(string_B)
```

You can do it in one line as:

```
string_A, string_B = string_B[0] + string_A[1:], string_A[0] + string_B[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

String (`str`) are immutables in Python.

You need to create a new string and affect it to the same identifier to get the result you want :

```py
string_A = "Fresh"
string_B = "Not fresh"

placeholder = string_A[0]
string_A = string_B[0] + string_A[1:]
string_B = placeholder + string_B[1:]

print(string_A)
print(string_B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable which means you can't update. Following is one way of doing what you asked for:

```
string_A = "Fresh"
string_B = "Not fresh"

a =  string_B[0:1] + string_A[1:]
b =  string_A[0:1] + string_B[1:]
print(a)
print(b)
```