# Pandas : TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a user defined table where a variable sting value will dictate the remaining set of records in my dataframe before it is converted to a dbf that the end-user will work on. The dataframe is created from a source dbf where records are added by user through a front end application. The users then need to run a python script where they will be prompted to provide their username. The Python script makes a pandas dataframe from the dbf but then needs to remove all records that were not created by the enduser.

```
Creator = 'johnsmith'

if Creator != '':
    df = df['Creator'] = Creator

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [23]:
Line 7:     df = df['Creator'] = Creator

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I did some research on this error and all of the examples I'm finding suggest iterating over singles characters in a string/list but I don't think the table dataframe properties are so straightforward to do that with:

['str' object does not support item assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631473/str-object-does-not-support-item-assignment)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `df['Creator'] = Creator` as opposed to what you have done.
See if this helps:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df=pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[i for i in range(10)]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6  6
7  7
8  8
9  9

In [4]: Creator = 'johnsmith'

In [5]: df['Creator']=Creator

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   a    Creator
0  0  johnsmith
1  1  johnsmith
2  2  johnsmith
3  3  johnsmith
4  4  johnsmith
5  5  johnsmith
6  6  johnsmith
7  7  johnsmith
8  8  johnsmith
9  9  johnsmith

In [7]: if Creator:
   ...:     df['Creator']=Creator
   ...:

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
   a    Creator
0  0  johnsmith
1  1  johnsmith
2  2  johnsmith
3  3  johnsmith
4  4  johnsmith
5  5  johnsmith
6  6  johnsmith
7  7  johnsmith
8  8  johnsmith
9  9  johnsmith
```

Reproducing your error:

```
In [9]: df = df['Creator'] = Creator
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-39082f896e58> in <module>
----> 1 df = df['Creator'] = Creator

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: I don't think that would work because I'm trying to select values from the dataframe based on the value of df['Creator'], not assign a value to the column. Basically, I want to remove all records that do not equal 'johnsmith'