# Removing tuple from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that allows the user to input student records, view records, delete records and display averages of marks. I am having trouble with removing a user inputted name from the list along with the students marks. This is the code i have so far

```
studentlist=[]
a=1
while a!=0:
    print ("""
1. Add new student records
2. Show all student records
3. Delete a student record
4. Dislay overall average coursework mark
5. Display overall average exam mark
6. Calculate average marks
0. Exit
Plese select an option
       """)
    a=int(input(""))
    if a==1:
        name=input("Enter a students name: ")
        cmark=int(input("Enter the students coursework mark: "))
        emark=int(input("Enter the students exam mark: "))
        student=(name,cmark,emark)
        print (student)
        studentlist.append(student)
        student=()
    if a==2:
        for n in studentlist:
            print ("Name:", n[0])
            print ("Courswork mark:",n[1])
            print ("Exam mark:", n[2])
            print ("")
    if a==3:
        name=input("Enter a students name: ")
        for n in studentlist:
            if n[0]==name:
                studentlist.remove(n[0])
                studentlist.remove(n[1])
                studentlist.remove(n[2])
```

Comment: See my edited answer for an example of using a `dict` instead of a `tuple`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't delete members of a `tuple` - you have to delete the entire `tuple`. For example:

```
x = (1,2,3)
assert x[0] == 1 #yup, works.
x.remove(0) #AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

`tuple`s are immutable, which means they can't be changed. As the error above explains, `tuple`s do not have a remove attribute/method (how could they? [they are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174124/why-do-we-need-tuples-in-python-or-any-immutable-data-type)).

Instead, try deleting the final three lines from your code sample above and replace them with the line below, which will simply remove the entire `tuple`:

```
studentlist.remove(n)
```

If you want to be able to change or delete individual grades (or correct a student's name), I suggest storing the student information in a `list` or a `dict` instead (example using a `dict` is below).

```
studentlist=[]
a=1
while a!=0:
    print ("""
1. Add new student records
2. Show all student records
3. Delete a student record
4. Dislay overall average coursework mark
5. Display overall average exam mark
6. Calculate average marks
0. Exit
Plese select an option
       """)
    a=int(input(""))
    if a==1:
        promptdict1 = {'name': 'Enter a students name: ', \
                       'cmark': 'Enter the students coursework mark: ', \
                       'emark': 'Enter the students exam mark: '}
        studentlist.append({'name': input(promptdict1['name']), \
                            'cmark': int(input(promptdict1['cmark'])), \
                            'emark': int(input(promptdict1['emark']))})
        print(studentlist[-1])
    if a==2:
        promptdict2 = {'name': 'Name:', \
                       'cmark': 'Courswork mark:', \
                       'emark': 'Exam mark:'}
        for student in studentlist:
            print(promptdict2['name'], student['name'])
            print(promptdict2['cmark'], student['cmark'])
            print(promptdict2['emark'], student['emark'], '\n')
    if a==3:
        name=input("Enter a students name: ")
        for n in studentlist:
            if n['name']==name:
                studentlist.remove(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

it probably makes more sense to just overwrite the old list with a new list

```
studentList = [item for item in studentList if item[0] != name]
```

if you really want to remove it you should not modify a list while you iterate over it...

```
for i,student in enumerate(studentList):
    if student[0] == name: 
       studentList.pop(i)
       break #STOP ITERATING NOW THAT WE CHANGED THE LIST
```