# Modifying Tensorflow constant Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've googled and came to know that Tensorflow's `constant()` function generates a constant Tensor (big surprise!) and cannot be modified.

But when I do:

```
>>> a = tf.constant(0.0)
>>> a = a + 1.0
```

I don't see any error generated by Tensorflow.

I understand the reason, `a` is now a new tensor operation `Add` (`<tf.Tensor 'add_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32>`).

My question is, What is the use of Tensorflow `constant` if we can modify it? Does it has anything to do with graph optimization? Am I missing something trivial here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2174170/4800086

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, you're missing something trivial.

```
 a = tf.constant(0.0)
```

`a` is a python variable that holds a constant node of the computational graph. In the graph it has a name, let's call it `constant:0`.

```
a = a + 1.0
```

`a` is a **new** python variable (the assignment is a destructive operation) that holds the add operation between the node `constant:0` that is still defined in the graph and a new constant node, automatically create when using `1.0` (`constant_1:0`).

Thus, in this line, you're overriding a python variable in order to make it holding an `add` node: you're **not** touching the values of the graph node `constant:0`.

The constant, in fact, is defined in the graph that tensorflow describes and it can't be changed.
What you can change, instead, is the python variable that points to a certain node in the graph.

You can think about the python variables as pointers to the graph's nodes.

Comment: Ah, now I understant. I mentioned "I understand the reason, a is now a new tensor operation Add" in the question, but I didn't see that Tensorflow dataflow graph and Python are two different things. Thank you

Comment: Is there any way to intentionally generate this error?

Comment: Is there any way I can generate a tensorflow error stating something like "cannot modify constant tensor"?

Comment: You can try to **assign into the graph** a value to a constant tensor. This will bring an error (because the constant object has no `assign` attribute). Just try `assign = tf.assign(a, 10.)` and `sess.run(assing)`. The program will crash at the like `tf.assing(a,10)` telling you that `Tensor object has no attribute assign`

Comment: Got it. Thank you.