# Python - Fastest way to create a tuple from a list with computations

Tags: python, list, tuples

I need to create in the fastest way possible a Python tuple from a list, but with intermediate computations. To be clearer I put a code snippet:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=tuple([id(x) for x in a])
```

This is what I have by now.
Is there something better than this? This code creates a list and then it converts it to a tuple, is there a way to directly create the tuple?

Thank you!

[EDIT]
As suggested I tried with

```
b=tuple(id(x) for x in a)
```

However it seems slower than before.
Test script:

```
import time

a=[1,2,3,4]

t1=time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    b=tuple([id(x) for x in a])
print(time.time()-t1)

t2=time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    b=tuple(id(x) for x in a)
print(time.time()-t2)
```

It was very unexpected to me.

Comment: `tuple(id(x) for x in a)` does not create intermediate lists

Comment: Thank, I did not know this possibility.
But It seems slower, I edit my question.

Comment: Are you doing this in Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but consider using the `timeit` module rather than `time.time` when comparing the run-time of code. `timeit` gives more reliable results because it runs each section multiple times, which lessens the impact of outside interference (such as Python going to sleep for a millisecond so the CPU can concentrate on a different application on your computer)

Comment: On Python 3.
@Kevin Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Using the list comprehension is *faster*. This is because the size of the tuple is known beforehand (memory can be allocated for `len(list)` items).

With generator, the generator needs to be converted to a sequence first  so that a tuple can be allocated. This will be slower because of the inherent overhead in generators.

---

The fastest option is naturally to *not* use a tuple at all and use a list instead. In my opinion, a tuple is not the same as "an immutable list"; one should really use tuple only when one needs to use a sequence as a dictionary key, or as a set element, or when you could *name* each element (as in `namedtuple`).

Comment: Ok, thanks. List does not fit for me since I need an immutable collection. Are there alternatives faster to tuples in this example?

Comment: @stefano1 Tuple is an immutable sequence of arbitrary elements. Used especially if you need it as a dictionary key or as an element in a set; for other cases list is as good, just say that it is not to be modified. After all, there is no such thing as a "immutable dictionary" for example.

Comment: I need it exactly as a dictionary key :) But thanks for your explanations in any case!

Comment: Could you expound why we shouldn't use tuples unnecessarily? I read in places such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48936610/13312697) that tuples of literals compute more quickly than lists.

Comment: @themadpsychologist yes but this is not a tuple of literals.

Comment: True. But why should we not use tuples unnecessarily? What advantages does a list have?