# Python Tuple vs List check for inclusion bytecode performance/size profiling

Tags: python

Given that the following code in python3.9 gives the same bytecode. (The List gets compiled to a Tuple)

```py
"x" in ["a", "b", "c"]
"x" in ("a", "b", "c")

  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('x')
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (('a', 'b', 'c'))
              4 CONTAINS_OP              0
              6 RETURN_VALUE
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('x')
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (('a', 'b', 'c'))
              4 CONTAINS_OP              0
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Why does timeit always say that a lookup in a tuple is faster than a lookup in an array?

Does timeit take into consideration compiling?

Similarly, when I use sys.getsizeof it says a Tuple uses less space.

When this code is ran, is there ever any space difference between the Tuple and the List in this example? Meaning, once compiled to bytecode there is no space difference if I'm understanding, but since a List is not immutable is the space allocated before the List is compiled into a Tuple?

```py
import dis
import sys
from timeit import timeit

bcode = dis.dis(lambda: "x" in ["a", "b", "c"])
bcode2 = dis.dis(lambda: "x" in ("a", "b", "c"))

# why is the bottom always faster? - accounts for compile/start up time?
print(timeit(lambda: "x" in ["a", "b", "c"]))
print(timeit(lambda: "x" in ("a", "b", "c")))
# 0.10836188100000001
# 0.10678786800000001

# similarly I get that this is just returning __sizeof__(), but in practice (execution) is there any memory difference since the bytecode is the same?
print(sys.getsizeof(["a", "b", "c"])) # 120
print(sys.getsizeof(("a", "b", "c"))) # 64
```

Comment: I just realized if I switch the order of the inclusion checks, whichever is second is faster. So something must caching the results but as to what mechanism is doing that, I'm not sure

Comment: For me, the tuples are always faster

Comment: If the bytecode is equivalent, **then it's exactly the same**. Yes, this is probably an artifact of the order in which you profile. These small differences are rarely important anyway

Comment: Tuples are faster than lists, you can refer to [Raymond's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48936610/8708364)

Comment: Note, this is an optimization that shouldn't be relied upon. "When this code is ran, is there ever any space difference between the Tuple and the List in this example?" **No** because **there is no list**. The compilation step ends up using a `tuple`. Of course, if you pass the object to `sys.getsizeof` then the compiler cannot make this optimization. This is the peep-hole optimizer for built-in literals

Comment: @U12-Forward the takeaway is "This gives tuples a small speed advantage for indexed lookups and unpacking". This should basically mean, in practice, **there is no significant difference**. Maybe if your code involves a lot of direct indexing, i.e. `mysequence[index]`. But most of the time, you are iterating directly over the sequence. The relevant difference between a tuple and a list **isn't performance**  it's the idiomatic way in which you'd use either type, a list for a homogenous, arbitrarily sized sequence, and a tuple to represent a product type