# Why can we define tuples with "empty" values in python?

Tags: python, tuples

python (2.7 in my case) has a several good looking ways to define tuples:

```
>>> a = (1,2,3)
>>> a
(1, 2, 3)
>>> a = 1,2,3
>>> a
(1, 2, 3)
```

But i don't understand why you can't define tuples with "empty" values, that you can't even access from index!

```
>>> a = 1,
>>> a
(1,)
>>> a[0]
1
>>> a[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

This behavior seems to be really error-prone. The second value of the tuple is "nothing", and it's not even None!

```
>>> a = 1,None
>>> a
(1, None)
```

I don't get the point of it, and it really feels like a bug. Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: No, there is *no second value*. The tuple contains only 1 item. Did you want your tuple to return 'something' for non-existing indices?

Comment: Are you asking why you need to use at least one comma to define a tuple instead?

Comment: `a = 1` is a variable containing one, the `a = (1)` is the same. Only `a = (1,)` creates a tuple with a single value.

Comment: Did you read [this section of tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)?

Comment: Is your confusion that there is a comma after the last item in the tuple as printed? That has always bothered me too - looks like lazy programming but there is probably a deeper reason. @MartijnPieters do you have any insights into that?

Comment: When defining a tuple, the `()` parenthesis are optional in many contexts. It is the *comma* that defines a tuple instead. But to create a tuple with one element, you need at least one comma. There is no second element there.

Comment: I've been debugging for almost half an hour to end up finding an extra comma in the code, transforming a string into a "1-item tuple". What's the point of defining a 1-item tuple? Why can we do that?

Comment: it's just a notation, don't take it literary

Comment: @Floris: The grammar allows for a trailing comma, because that makes maintenance of sequences with constants **much** easier, as well as making diffs between edits clearer (just add another line with `newvalue,` instead of having to tack on the missing comma on the preceding line too).

Comment: @Sebastien: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828041/are-there-any-uses-of-the-empty-tuple-in-python

Comment: @Sebastien: Because `(1)` is not a tuple. It is an expression in parenthesis.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - as usual you came through. Thanks!

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: thx, you helped me get why empty tuples and one item tuples are usefull. Making recursive algorithms possible on tuples is indeed a very good reason.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: ok, i get this and i agree with you. But then, i think that the tuple definition syntax without parenthesis is error-prone and shouldn't be accepted by python since it's not necessary.

Comment: @Sebastien: feel free to suggest that as a change in Python 4, but they're not going away in Python 2 or 3.

Comment: it's a dynamic language. that's why you do unit tests.

Comment: @Sebastien: it is fantastically useful, and most people use it all the time without realizing it. Ever swapped variables with `a, b = b, a`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: (a,b)=(b,a) still works! Well, the question is going off-topic, but IMO, we should forbid the other syntax to detect more human mistakes while programming.

Comment: @Sebastien: Really, the mistake happens rarely enough. And Python syntax is not going to change that dramatically unless there is going to be a Python 4 (not likely anytime soon).

Comment: Because `(1)` is an integer not a tuple. You have to write it with a comma `(1,)` so it becomes a tuple.