# why would I create an empty tuple in python

Tags: python, tuples

Can anyone give me an example of why I would need to create/use an empty tuple and why it would be considered useful? I understand tuples are immutable and created using  `()`.

Comment: Is there any similar usage pattern you came across which led to this question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828041/are-there-any-uses-of-the-empty-tuple-in-python

Comment: You might have a function that iterates over an iterable, like a list or tuple. It might be easier to pass an empty tuple, such that looping over it does nothing, instead of adding special logic to handle None

Comment: You can start with an empty tuple as an accumulator and "add" values to it in a loop. Same as with an empty string.

Comment: @DYZ -- Surely a `list` is a more appropriate data structure for that case ...

Comment: @mgilson Surely. But the OT wanted an example of an empty tuple use.

Comment: You can use an empty `tuple()` as a sentinel, e.g.: `for chunk in iter(lambda: tuple(it.islice(iterable, length)), tuple()):`

Comment: One place that I find myself using this is when creating default arguments for functions:  `def foo(sequence=()): ...`, We don't want to use a list here because then you get into the "mutable default argument" badness, we could use `None`, but then we need to check before we do any sequence operations on it (e.g. iterating).  An empty tuple supports sequence operations _and_ it's immutable so we're golden...