# Pythonic way to calculate offsets of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to calculate the origin and offset of variable size arrays and store them in a dictionary.  Here is the likely non-pythonic way that I am achieving this.  I am not sure if I should be looking to use map, a lambda function, or list comprehensions to make the code more pythonic.

Essentially, I need to cut chunks of an array up based on the total size and store the xstart, ystart, x_number_of_rows_to_read, y_number_of_columns_to_read in a dictionary.  The total size is variable.  I can not load the entire array into memory and use numpy indexing or I definitely would.  The origin and offset are used to get the array into numpy.

```
intervalx = xsize / xsegment #Get the size of the chunks
intervaly = ysize / ysegment #Get the size of the chunks

#Setup to segment the image storing the start values and key into a dictionary.
xstart = 0
ystart = 0
key = 0

d = defaultdict(list)

for y in xrange(0, ysize, intervaly):
    if y + (intervaly * 2) < ysize:
        numberofrows = intervaly
    else:
        numberofrows = ysize - y

    for x in xrange(0, xsize, intervalx):
        if x + (intervalx * 2) < xsize:
            numberofcolumns = intervalx

        else:
            numberofcolumns = xsize - x
        l = [x,y,numberofcolumns, numberofrows]
        d[key].append(l)
        key += 1
return d
```

I realize that xrange is not ideal for a port to 3.

Comment: xrange is fine -- 2to3 handles that one without any problems.

Comment: have you considered `h5py`. It allows you to use [`numpy` syntax to work with arrays](http://h5py.alfven.org/docs-2.0/intro/quick.html#getting-your-data-back) without loading all elements into memory

Comment: I have considered both h5py and using numpy.memmap, but do not believe I can apply them.  Specifically, the array is an image, not raw array, and I am using GDAL to read the image as a numpy array.  I would need to strip off the header, then process the array, then reapply the header.  Would direct disk access be possible / better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code looks fine except for your use of `defaultdict`.  A list seems like a much better data structure because:

- Your keys are sequential
- you are storing a list whose only element is another list in your dict.

One thing you could do:

- use the ternary operator (I'm not sure if this would be an improvement, but it would be fewer lines of code)

Here's a modified version of your code with my few suggestions.

```
intervalx = xsize / xsegment #Get the size of the chunks
intervaly = ysize / ysegment #Get the size of the chunks

#Setup to segment the image storing the start values and key into a dictionary.
xstart = 0
ystart = 0

output = []

for y in xrange(0, ysize, intervaly):
    numberofrows = intervaly if y + (intervaly * 2) < ysize else ysize -y
    for x in xrange(0, xsize, intervalx):
        numberofcolumns = intervalx if x + (intervalx * 2) < xsize else xsize -x
        lst = [x, y, numberofcolumns, numberofrows]
        output.append(lst)

        #If it doesn't make any difference to your program, the above 2 lines could read:
        #tple = (x, y, numberofcolumns, numberofrows)
        #output.append(tple)

        #This will be slightly more efficient 
        #(tuple creation is faster than list creation)
        #and less memory hungry.  In other words, if it doesn't need to be a list due
        #to other constraints (e.g. you append to it later), you should make it a tuple.
```

Now to get your data, you can do `offset_list=output[5]` instead of `offset_list=d[5][0]`

Comment: Thanks, I had not considered using a list, but it does make more sense than using a dictionary as I do not need to track position by key.

Comment: a tuple or even a namedtuple instead of a sublist seems like a better fit here.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian -- Why do you say that?  The OP is using sequential numbers starting from 0.  Why is a namedtuple better for that?  Building this as a tuple initially would be difficult.  Of course, converting it to a tuple after the fact is trivial, but I'm not really sure what the point is in doing that ...

Comment: if you drop `[]` in the `lst = [...]` line you get a tuple. Nothing difficult

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian -- OH, that list.  Yes, you're right, tuples are better for that one.  (I thought you were talking about the list `output`, but I suppose that is why you used the term 'sublist' :D.)  I'll edit.

Comment: @Jzl5325 -- See the comments I've added due to a great comment by J.F.Sebastian.  If you take his suggestion, it should make this code slightly more efficient with almost no work on your part.

Comment: @mgilson Thanks!  I did not know that a tuple would be a better choice and / or faster.  I will make the change.  Unfortunately, these lines are fast already, but I will take any speedup to offset the IO issues I have using GDAL.

Comment: I wanted to get a better handle on this as I assumed the only difference was mutability, and came across this post.  Quite good.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1708538/839375

Comment: @Jzl5325: the reason to use tuples is not speed but the semantics that they communicate: [Tuples have structure, lists have order.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/626871/4279)

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't change your algorithm, a more pythonic way to write your if/else statements is:

```
numberofrows = intervaly if y + intervaly * 2 < ysize else ysize - y
```

instead of this:

```
if y + (intervaly * 2) < ysize:
    numberofrows = intervaly
else:
    numberofrows = ysize - y
```

(and similarly for the other if/else statement).

Comment: Why's that more Pythonic? It's much harder to parse. Ternary conditionals should be used sparingly.

Comment: I checked out the ternary posting on wikipedia and am not seeing the improvement in either readability or speed.  What is the purpose of ternary conditionals in a language like python?

Comment: Since what is 'pythonic' is subjective outside of PEP8, this is just what I was taught. I personally find it just as readable, and in some cases more readable, especially in cases where they similar constructs occur multiple times in the same block. Anyway, to each his/her own.

Comment: @Jzl5325 The ternary conditional was only added in 2.5, so it clearly wasn't core. I think its value is when you have a simple boolean variable: `extinguisher = water if paper_fire else co2`.

Comment: @HenryGomersall That does make sense and is more readable.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `np.memmap` to load the pieces dynamically instead? You would then just need to determine the offsets that you need on the fly rather than chunking the array storing the offsets.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html

Comment: Yes, but see my comment on the original post.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long one liner :

```
d = [(x,y,min(x+xinterval,xsize)-x,min(y+yinterval,ysize)-y) for x in 
xrange(0,xsize,xinterval) for y in xrange(0,ysize,yinterval)]
```