# check equality against a collection of values

Tags: python, equality

Suppose I want to check if a variable equals one of several values. Which of the following expressions should I use?

```
if s == 'one' or s == 'two' or s == 'three':
    pass

if s in ('one', 'two', 'three'):
    pass

if s in ['one', 'two', 'three']:
    pass

if s in {'one', 'two', 'three'}:
    pass
```

**EDIT:** From the answers / comments, I understood that:

- The first variant is least recommended, the others are considered equally "pythonic".
- The Performance differences in checking membership are negligible, for a short sequence. Tuples are least costly to create, sets require computing hashes.
- The four variants are not equivalent in some edge cases:

  - The `in` operator checks for both identity and equality.
  - Logical `or` is short-circuited. I suspect that Membership tests of tuples and lists should be evaluated sequentially and thus be short-circuited, too.
  - Sets require hashable elements.

Comment: I usually use sets as complexity there is O(1).

Comment: The last one is theoretically faster if you can reuse the set, but for only three items there is no substantial difference.

Comment: 1. No 2. Ok 3. a bit more expensive than 2 but still Ok 4. More expensive to create, fastest check, good if the set is reused.

Comment: Check also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exist-in-a-list).

Comment: Note that they are not strictly all equivalent `==` checks equality but the `in` operator checks both equality or identity

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Using lists and tuples in Python if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409457/using-lists-and-tuples-in-python-if-statements)

Comment: @Chris_Rands: So `in` checks identity first, and then equality?

Comment: @NicolasMalebranche Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48867273/6260170

Answer (score 1):

I think the below three are the best:

```
if s in ('one', 'two', 'three'):
    pass

if s in ['one', 'two', 'three']:
    pass

if s in {'one', 'two', 'three'}:
    pass
```

But maybe still:

```
if s in {'one', 'two', 'three'}:
    pass
```

Is still the best

## Timing

```
%timeit if 'one' in ('one', 'two', 'three'):pass
```

Output:

```
The slowest run took 21.60 times longer than the fastest. This could mean 
that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 63.4 ns per loop
```

&

```
%timeit if 'one' in ['one', 'two', 'three']:pass
```

Output:

```
 10000000 loops, best of 3: 50.7 ns per loop
```

&

```
%timeit if 'one' in {'one', 'two', 'three'}:pass
```

Output:

```
10000000 loops, best of 3: 50.3 ns per loop
```

At the end i prefer `set`(`{}`) because it is the fastest

and the tuple is the slowest it what i least prefer (in the tuple, list and set)

Comment: You should really say *why* you think these are best

Comment: Good! I don't think you can draw clear conclusions from those timings though

Comment: I got different results. Sets took about 20% of the time of lists and tuples, which were both very similar. The test was finding a character in a collection of 52 characters, which is obviously a lot more than the asker was looking for, but probably a more applicable test for the efficiency of sets over lists and tuples.

Answer (score 1):

With three values to check, it does not matter.

The first one `if s == 'one' or s == 'two' or s == 'three':` is arguably the less pythonic. It may be handy in the **case where one of the value is much more likely than the other**. In that case, you take advantage of lazy evaluation by placing the most likely values up front, thus avoiding evaluating the entire expression most of the time.

Using a set `if s in {'one', 'two', 'three'}:` carries the cost of creating the set `O(n)` hashes upfront, but will pay large dividends in the case where there are many variables to check, many times, or if the collection contains many duplicates.

The other two are mostly identical. I have a slight preference for a tuple which is immutable, vs a list, but that is for reasons not directly related to the question.

Timing the performance differences for the case of 3 values is not useful.

Comment: I can hardly recommend the looping example, when you can use `if 'one' in ('one', 'two', 'three')` as shown in the question.

Comment: I agree, I removed it as it was indeed redundant

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `set` if you will repeat multiple times or have to deal with many alternatives.

However, if you only use it once, it is recommended to use `tuples`.

The first type is not recommended under any circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the options you proposed, though the first one if probably the less convenient to use.

The last option using `set` is supposed to be the most efficient in terms of performance, but it really depends on how long is your collection.

If you don't have thousands of entries in your collection, just use a list, it's more common and more flexible for any usage.