# Using a list as a Listbox variable rather than a tuple

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to have a list as a Tkinter Listbox listvariable? Or does it have to be a tuple? I would really like to make changes in the list and therefore I can't use a tuple. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `list()` and/or `tuple()` functions? Using these you could make a list into a tuple or a tuple into a list.

```
alist = [1,2,3]
atuple = (4,5,6)

new_tuple = tuple(alist)   # returns (1,2,3) which is a tuple
new_list = list(atuple)    # returns [4,5,6] which is a list
```

So if the listvariable returns data as a tuple, then you could read the list (using the `get()` method), change it to a list type (using `list()`), make your changes and pass your data back (using the `tuple()` and `set()` methods). However, in general if some widget only works with a given variable type, think about why that is and why your data is not of the same type.

---

There are a couple of good questions here about when/why to use lists or tuples in Python.

[python: list vs tuple, when to use each?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1708510/404469)

- the accepted answer suggests tuples are commonly used for heterogeneous data and lists for data that is homogeneous
- another answer points out that tuples are immutable (data cannot be changed in place once assigned) while lists are mutable

Another question ([What's the difference between list and tuples in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/626759/404469)) mentions these same points and links to a couple articles on the topic.

Lastly, this link on the [Listbox widget](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/listbox.html) mentions the `listvariable` and its `get`/`set` methods.