# Python method-list

Tags: python, list, methods

in Python3.2 I'm trying to do a list:

```
>> ls = 1, 2, 3
>> ls
(1, 2, 3)
>> ls.append(4)
```

And with this last command, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Why is this? How can I solve it?
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 6):

The syntax for a list is `[1, 2, 3]`.

`(1, 2, 3)` is a tuple.

Lists are mutable, but tuples are immutable. That is, tuples can't be modified after they have been created (which is why you can't `append` to them).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708510/python-list-vs-tuple-when-to-use-each) has great insight as to when you'd use one over the other.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was a great help.