# What is "homogenous" in Python list documentation?

Tags: python, list

In python documentation list is defined as:

> mutable sequences, typically used to store collections of homogeneous items (where the precise degree of similarity will vary by application).

Why it's used to store collections of **homogeneous** items?

Are a string and an int item also homogeneous then?

```
a = [12,"hello"]
```

Comment: It's the dictionary term: "of the same type"

Comment: Strange choice of wording.  The only thing homogeneous I can see here is that they are python objects.

Comment: Related: [python: list vs tuple, when to use each?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708510/python-list-vs-tuple-when-to-use-each)

Comment: "Typically" used. The most common use of a list is to iterate over it, so it would be expected that each `i` in `for i in myList` provides the same functionality. Also, the homogeneity of a list would be determined by what functionality is expected of the the items. If the only requirement is that `str(i)` return a usable string, `12` and `"hello"` could well be considered the same "type".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Homogeneous means ["of the same or a similar kind or nature"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homogeneous).

While *any* value can be stored in a list along with any other value, in doing so the definition of "kind or nature" must be *widened* when dealing with the sequence. During this widening (or "unification"), the set of operations that can be performed upon *every* item in the sequence becomes the "lowest common set of operations" shared between *all* items.

This is why "[list are] *typically* used to store collections of homogeneous items" - so the items in the sequence can be treated with an appropriate level of unification:

```
# a list of animals that can "speak"
animals = [Dog(), Cat(), Turkey()]
for a in animals:
  a.speak()

# .. but a string cannot "speak"
animals = [Dog(), "Meow!", Turkey()]
```

Answer (score 2):

While you technically can store any object in a list:

```
[12, "hello", list, list()]
```

Lists are, as the documentation says, *usually* used to store similar items:

```
[12, 24, 99]
["hello", "goodbye"]
[list, dict, int]
```

The meaning of "homogenous" is simply "similar".

Answer (score 2):

It talks about a common use case (that's why it says "typically"). Homogeneity is neither expected nor enforced, as illustrated by the example in your question. Even what it means for items to be "homogenous" is not precisely defined: the doc says that this "will vary by application".