# Python: randomly assigning titles to documents in a corpus

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

- I have a large document corpus, `D` which is basically a Python list of *n* filtered tweets.

  For example, `D[0]` is "*New Exploit to 'Hack Android Phones Remotely' threatens Millions of Devices*"

  Also, *n* is of the order 10^4.
- Say, there's another list of *m = 10* topics for my documents in `Z`, that I wish to randomly assign to each document and,

  `Z = ['hack', 'tools', 'android', 'google', 'anonymous', ... ]`.

How do I go about creating an *n x 2* array, such that that the assignment of topics is (as close to) a truly random process?

---

Edit:

I'm not sure how to code this. Sorry if the explanation is a little vague, but there isn't much information to give. I simply want a way to map from `Z` to `D`, *randomly* (to obtain an *n x 2* array **not** an *n x m* array, honest mistake).

Comment: It would be helpful if you clarify your question with a simple example using small values of n and m. Also, you should post your own attempt at coding this.

Comment: @PM2Ring I've added as much detail as I could. There's not a lot going on in the code itself. I simply want to map from Z to D, *randomly*.

Comment: I can show you how to build a Python list of _n_ rows. The _i_ th row consists of _m_ tuples. Each tuple pairs the _i_ th tweet with one of the _m_ topics, in random order. Would that help?

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, that should work. I realised that I don't need an n x m matrix at all.

Comment: Take a look at [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice); numpy may provide something similar, but I don't know numpy.

Comment: Yeah, I was confused by _why_ you wanted a `nxm` array. :)

Comment: Turns out there's also a [numpy.random.choice](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). Worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after.

```
>>> D = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> Z = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
>>> [[i, random.choice(Z)] for i in D]
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'd'], [3, 'c'], [4, 'f'], [5, 'b'], [6, 'g'], [7, 'f'], [8, 'f'], [9, 'f']]
```

This list comprehension iterates through `D` (Your corpus) and matches each element to a random element of `Z` (your topics).

Tuples might be a better choice than lists for the individual pairs though, as they are more commonly used to represent a collection of different things - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1708610/3714940) answer for when to use Lists vs Tuples.

Comment: I might, in fact, need tuples afterall. Thank you.