# Is this 'file' entity a tuple?

Tags: python

```
file = ('cropdata.txt')
```

I am not really sure what a tuple is. Here is `file` a tuple? How do tuples differ from lists or strings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples just search

Comment: use `type(file)` to actually see the type of the object, experiment with a few different notations and you will find the  answer yourself.

Answer (score 6):

No, `file` is a string.  If you're creating a tuple from individual objects, [they always need to be separated by commas](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).  This includes tuples with only a single object (put the comma after the item) because otherwise, the interpreter will use the parenthesis to group the expression for order of operations.

```
this_is_a_tuple = ('cropdata.txt',)  # Parenthesis are used for Order-of-operations grouping
this_is_a_string = ('cropdata.txt')  # Notice, no comma.
this_is_also_a_tuple = 'cropdata.txt',
```

However, an empty tuple is created with empty parenthesis:

```
this_is_an_empty_tuple = ()  # Look mom, no comma!
```

---

As for what a tuple *is* -- it's simply an object that holds references to other objects.  The other objects can be looked up by index:

```
my_tuple = ('foo', 2)
my_tuple[0]  # foo
my_tuple[1]  # 2
```

Tuples are also iterable:

```
for item in my_tuple:
    ...
```

If you're familiar with `list` objects, `tuple` are very similar.  The key difference is that a `tuple` is *immutable* -- Once created, you can't change the tuple (though you might be able to change objects that the tuple holds).  The benefits of immutability (and related hashability) are a bit beyond the scope of this question and are answered really well elsewhere... For further discussion, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1708510/748858) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples).

Comment: To add, tuples are immutable while lists can be modified. For instance, you couldn't say my_tuple[0] = 'somethingelse' but you could if it was a list.

Comment: @BrianSchlenker -- Yep, I was just adding that in.

Comment: You might consider changing "If you're creating a tuple from individual objects" to "If you're creating a tuple _with only a single object in it_" the way you have it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen -- Mostly I was trying to cut out the case of `tuple(some_iterable)` ... But what I have is technically wrong because `()` is the way that an empty tuple is created ...

Comment: "A tuple literal with a single element requires a trailing comma" perhaps? nevermind, link to documentation is sufficient.