# python argparse choices with a default choice

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm trying to use argparse in a Python 3 application where there's an explicit list of choices, but a default if none are specified.

The code  I have is:

```
parser.add_argument('--list', default='all', choices=['servers', 'storage', 'all'], help='list servers, storage, or both (default: %(default)s)') 
args = parser.parse_args()
print(vars(args))
```

However, when I run this I get the following with an option:

```
$ python3 ./myapp.py --list all
{'list': 'all'}
```

Or without an option:

```
$ python3 ./myapp.py --list
usage: myapp.py [-h] [--list {servers,storage,all}]
myapp.py: error: argument --list: expected one argument
```

Am I missing something here? Or can I not have a default with choices specified?

Comment: Don't pass `--list` at all and your default will be used.

Comment: I see... That'd work except for the fact that I need to tell it to list, create, delete, etc.

Comment: Sounds like you want [subcommands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands), not a switch at all. Even with `nargs='?'` you can't tell the difference between `--list` and not passing anything when there is a default set.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks @ShadowRanger.  `Subcommands` is exactly what I need, combined with `nargs` and `const`.  The following works:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparser = parser.add_subparsers()
parser_list = subparser.add_parser('list')
parser_list.add_argument('list_type', default='all', const='all', nargs='?', choices=['all', 'servers', 'storage'])

parser_create = subparser.add_parser('create')
parser_create.add_argument('create_type', default='server', const='server', nargs='?', choices=['server', 'storage'])

args = parser.parse_args()
pprint(vars(args))

$ python3 ./myapp.py -h
usage: dotool.py [-h] {list,create} ...

Digital Ocean tool

positional arguments:
  {list,create}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
```

list option alone:

```
$ python3 ./myapp.py list
{'list_type': 'all'}
```

List option with a parameter:

```
$ python3 ./myapp.py list servers
{'list_type': 'servers'}
```

Comment: Can we add help description for positional arguments? such as for `{list,create}`

Answer (score 125):

Pass the `nargs` and `const` arguments to `add_argument`:

```
parser.add_argument('--list',
                    default='all',
                    const='all',
                    nargs='?',
                    choices=['servers', 'storage', 'all'],
                    help='list servers, storage, or both (default: %(default)s)')
```

If you want to know if `--list` was passed without an argument, remove the `const` argument, and check if `args.list` is `None`.

---

Documention:

[`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) with `'?'`

> One argument will be consumed from the command line if possible, and produced as a single item. If no command-line argument is present, the value from `default` will be produced. Note that for optional arguments, there is an additional case - the option string is present but not followed by a command-line argument. In this case the value from `const` will be produced.

[`const`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#const)

> When `add_argument()` is called with option strings (like `-f` or `--foo`) and `nargs='?'`. This creates an optional argument that can be followed by zero or one command-line arguments. When parsing the command line, if the option string is encountered with no command-line argument following it, the value of `const` will be assumed instead. See the nargs description for examples.

Comment: Kind of a nit, but I'd use a tuple instead of a list:

`choices=('servers','storage','all')` 
for the reasons discussed at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708510/list-vs-tuple-when-to-use-each] (Lists vs Tuples)