# Sort dataframe by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need to sort(in a descending order) a dataframe according to multiple columns using the following piece of code:

```
df = df.sort_values(measures, ascending = (False,False,False,False,False))
```

where 'measures' is a list of columns names. As a result I only get the dataframe sorted by the first column (ms1) in 'measures' list.

a snippet of the dataframe before sorting:

```
     Features      ms1    ...            ms4           ms5
0        age       0.188  ...            0.025         0.994
1        sex       0.556  ...            0.040         8.080
2         cp       0.437  ...            0.054         20.121
3   trestbps       0.199  ...            0.015         0.512
4       chol       0.194  ...            0.002         0.085
5        fbs       0.622  ...            0.030         0.055
```

And after sorting:

```
     Features      ms1    ...            ms4           ms5
5        fbs       0.622  ...            0.030         0.055
8      exang       0.593  ...            0.023         36.842
1        sex       0.556  ...            0.040         8.080
12      thal       0.527  ...            0.007         1.902
6    restecg       0.488  ...            0.067         1.219
```

does anyone know why it is not working properly

Comment: What you are passing to the `ascending` parameter is a tuple when a list is required. Might be worth it to read up on the differences which should help understand why you will generally see that parameters will require lists vs tuples. Here is a good post on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708510/list-vs-tuple-when-to-use-each

Comment: @Timbolt I actually did use a list instead of a tuple but had the same output!

Answer (score 1):

`'ascending'` parameter takes a bool or list of bool as per [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).
So, try this instead -

```
df.sort_values(measures, ascending = [False,False,False,False,False])
```

Answer (score 1):

When you sorted by the first column(ms1) the another columns is following the ms1.But if there are same value in ms1 then the same values rows will sorted values by the second column.And so on...